# How can I update the metadata of spl token which have disabled mint authority?

Tags: spl-token, web3.js

I need to update the metadata of spl token which have mint authority disabled after minting the token like

1. Mint random token in devnet
2. Disable mint
3. Update metadata of spl token.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, since the metaplex metadata requires the mint authority to sign for changes to the metadata.  You must keep around the mint authority long enough to perform the update.